# Webpage has top padding - cant get rid of it

Tags: css, html

I'm going crazy trying to get rid of this small padding at the top of the webpage. It shows up in all browsers.
 Here is a pic[image: pic]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="mainpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Mobile Development</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topnavcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cloud</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>  
<div id="bodycontainer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File mainpage.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body
{
background: #000000;
font-family: Georgia, Serif;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#topnavcontainer
{
height:5em;
background-color:#0f0f0f;
background-image: url(Images/crosshatch.png);
}

#navlist li
{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;    
}

#navlist a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
color:white;
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}

html {
margin: 0;
}

body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked, can you explain to me why  *{margin:0;} worked and what it is for?

Comment: @spentak: It's known as a browser reset. This one in particular isn't a very complete one. The `*` rule in CSS will match all elements

Comment: @spentak: the fact that it worked means you have a particular element that causes it. Rather than define all `margin`s as 0, you should find the problematic element. I suspect it is `li`.

Comment: @spentak margin is the spacing outside the box, padding is spacing within the box.

Comment: Oh, `* span {}` (for example) only works in IE. I confused them.

Comment: @Justin you can set the * attribute at the top of the css file and then when you want elements that require margin then you can set that. That's the beauty of css, the latter element's properties takes precedence.

Comment: @Justin: Actually, that will work in most current browsers I'm aware of too. I've not heard of `*` not being supported properly in current browsers before. You may be confusing the prefix hack where IE will read specific rules like `*width: xpx` when it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I avoid IE hacks so I had become rusty with them. You are right. Still, unless he is practicing full CSS reset, I think just resetting the `margin`s is kind of superfluous when he is only doing it to fix the margin for one particular element.

Comment: @Justin: So do I, but you do see them about the place, so it helps to know about them, even if it's only to know what to avoid.

Comment: I avoid setting things on `*` because `*` targets `input` tags, and that can make them ugly.

Comment: @spentak, try a google search for css tutorials. search for the difference between padding and margin too!

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Also, your `<meta>` tag has borked syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ul` and `li`s that are the links in your navigation bar have top margin that need to be removed.

```
ul, li {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: li comes with a default margin?

Comment: `ul` does, not necessarily `li` like I originally said.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser has it's own default CSS rules for the HTML tags. You should use a CSS reset (eg: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove the properties set by the browsers' CSS (in your page the ul element has the default CSS properties which defines some margins for it). A rule like:

```
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

should remove the default formatting for the ul element.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, you're not resetting your css styles properly so the default margin of the `ul` of your menu is displaying that extra margin on top. Here is a quick fix to this problem:

```
ul#navlist {
   margin:0;
}
```

Though i highly recommend a reset sheet, with a simple include of this sheet the problem is resolved: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/